# How to get JobParameter and JobExecutionContext in the ItemWriter?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I want to retrieve `JobParameter` and `JobExecutionContext` object in my `ItemWriter` class.
How to  proceed?

I tried implementing `StepExecutionListener` through which I am just calling the parent class methods.  But it is not succeeding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have solved the above problem by extending StepExecutionListenerSupport class.After that override parent class method that is'beforeStep'                                     public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub this.stepExecution = stepExecution; }

Comment: I faced the same problem and tried your solution by extending StepExecutionListenerSupport class, and the afterStep and beforeStep methods were not called.  
Was your ItemWriter a StepScoped Bean? I faced the same problem when my ItemWriter was a stepscoped bean. On changing back to singleton bean, the beforeStep and after methods were called.

Comment: If your requirement was to have the writer as a StepExecutionListener and also stepScoped, this is the solution.. and this worked for me. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21941127/3004747

Answer (score 25):

Implementing StepExecutionListener is one way.  In fact that's the only way in Spring Batch 1.x.

Starting from Spring Batch 2, you have another choice: You can inject whatever entries in Job Parameters and Job Execution Context to your item writer.  Make your item writer with `step` scope, then make use of expression like `#{jobParameters['theKeyYouWant']}` or `#{jobExecutionContext['someOtherKey']}` for value injecting to you item writer.

Comment: Adrian, can you clarify this is the correct way to inject the JobExecutionContext into an item reader, writer, or processor: 1) in config, inject into the bean: <property name="context" value"#{jobExecutionContext}"/>, then 2) in the bean:  private JobExecutionContext context; (no need for @Value) Is there anything missing or wrong? Thanks very much

Comment: 1. you need the bean being step scope, 2. you need setter for "context" property.

Comment: How does it behave when executing many jobs at once? any thread safe problems?

Comment: Step scope is going to make a new instance for each step execution.

Comment: @Adrain If we are passing data through jobExecutionContext then is it necessary to configure ExecutionContextPromotionListener  with the keys ?

Comment: @user1919581 You may.  However it has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Making my itemWriter StepScope gives a null pointer exception

Answer (score 23):

Use the `@BeforeStep` annotation to call a method before step processing.

```
//From the StepExecution get the current running JobExecution object.
public class MyDataProcessor implements ItemProcessor<MyDataRow, MyDataRow> {
    private JobExecution jobExecution;

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

To add to Adrian Shum's answer, if you want to avoid each job parameter to be injected as a class property, you can directly inject the `Map` of `JobParameter`s as follows:

```
@Value("#{jobParameters}")
private Map<String, JobParameter> jobParameters;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Spring Configuration file, you can access the StepExecution object with:

```
<bean id="aaaReader" class="com.AAAReader" scope="step">
    <property name="stepExecution" value="#{stepExecution}" />
</bean>
```

In AAAReader class you need to create the proper field and a setter:

```
private StepExecution stepExecution;

public void setStepExecution(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
}
```

Same for Processor and Writer classes.

Comment: Wondering why did I got a down vote on this - without a comment?

Comment: is it possible to use your solution to access step execution from a listener. more precisely a class that implement ItemProcessorListener