# How to access stepExecution in partitioner

Tags: spring-batch

We are using partitioner and it is annotated with @Scope(value="step") and has setter method which is annotated with @BeforeStep, but still framewowrk does not inject step execution object?

What we are doing wrong

Comment: What so you want to do? the partitioner creates (step-) executions, it makes no sense (for me) to participate in a step lifecycle

Answer (score 2):

Did you register the partitioner as "listener" on the step? As soon as you are using Step-Scope, your Bean is hidden behind a proxy, which makes it impossible for spring to register it automatically as a step-listener (it should work if your bean is not "step-scoped").

It is explained here:
[Spring-batch @BeforeStep does not work with @StepScope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241683/spring-batch-beforestep-does-not-work-with-stepscope)