# How to get stepExecutionContext in Processor using CompositeItemProcessor?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

In XML file i have configured two Processor using **CompositeItemProcessor**

```
    <processor>
          <beans:bean id="CompositeItemProcessor" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor" scope="step">
            <beans:property name="delegates">
              <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="oldProcessor"/>
                <beans:ref bean="newProcessor"/>
              </beans:list>
            </beans:property>
          </beans:bean>
        </processor>
```

and in "**oldProcessor**" bean java file i have added below code to get **StepExecution** object.

```
      @BeforeStep
      @Order(1)
      public void setStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
      }
```

but above code not executing. only **process()** method calling  from "**oldProcessor**" bean.

and when i tried without configuring  **CompositeItemProcessor**,then this "**setStepExecution()**" method and **process()** method are executing of oldProcessor bean. 
eg.

```
<processor>
    <beans:ref bean="oldProcessor"/>
</processor>
```

Please advise me, how to get stepExecutionContext in Processor using CompositeItemProcessor

Comment: Since you are using XML config and have a setter for the step execution, have you tried to inject the step execution with a SpEL expression? Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44967412/5019386

Comment: yes, i tried but same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following in your processor.

```
@Value("#{stepExecution}")

private StepExecution stepExecution;
```

This should work if the scope is step.